# Is there a way to install mingw-64 on windows in a virtual enviroment?

Tags: mingw-w64, facebook-prophet, python-3.7, pystan

Im trying to install pystan and facebook-prophet in a virtual enviroment. But it needed mingw-64 and libpython in able to run it. All the instructions are using conda. Is there a way to install mingw-64 and libpython in a virtual enviroment without using conda but just pip?

I downloaded the mingw-64 from the website. But i dont want to install it directly into my system, i want to install it in a virtual env. But cannot find any instructions how to that.

[image]